# What are meta-level and object-level proofs?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, formal-languages

I am reading "handbook of knowledge representation" and here the author mentioned two kinds of proofs for propositional logic: Meta-level and object-level proofs. It says:

> When we want to establish that a formula $F$ is entailed by a knowledge base $ \Gamma$, the straightforward approach is to use the deﬁnition of entailment, that is, to reason about interpretations of the underlying signature. For instance, to check that the formulas $\lnot p$ and $q \rightarrow r$ entail $(p \lor q) \rightarrow r$ we can argue that no interpretation of the signature $\{p, q, r\}$ can satisfy both $\lnot p$ and $q \rightarrow r$ unless it satisfies $(p \lor q) \rightarrow r$ as well.
>
> A sound deductive system provides an “object-level” alternative to **this meta-level** approach. Once we proved the sequent $\Gamma \implies F$ in the deductive system described above, we have established that Γ entails F.

I am quite confused. From "this meta-level approach", it can be inferred that the author means the way he mentioned of checking interpretations of $\{p,q,r\}$ is **meta-level proof**.

Then he goes:

> For instance, the claim that the formulas $\lnot p$ and $q \rightarrow r$ entail $(p \lor q) \rightarrow r$ is justiﬁed by **Fig. 1.2**. Since the system is not only sound but also complete, the object-level approach to establishing entailment is, in principle, always applicable.

Fig.1.2 is a proof procedure of the entailment above:

[Fig1.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fowgQ.png)

Now I don't understand if Fig1.2 shown above is an object-level or a meta-level proof? And what is the essential difference between these two?

My understanding now is that object-level focus more on the specific atoms while meta-level focus more on $left \implies right$, which is more high-level. But I really don't understand the author here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proof shown in the linked Figure is a *derivation* in the propositional calculus.

It is said at "object level" because the propositional calculus is the "object" we are using to perform derivation (i.e. calculations with formulas and rules of inference).

At the "meta level", we are studying the mathematical properties of the mathematical object : *propositional calculus*, like e.g. consistency, soundness, completeness.

These properties are established trhough proofs that are "usual" pieces of mathematical reasoning regarding the calculus.

When we say e.g. that the propositional formula $p ∨ ¬p$ is a theorem of the calculus we can work two ways :

either *(i)* provide a derivation of it (i.e. $⊢ p ∨ ¬p$), from the axiom of the calculus, and this is an object-level proof,

or *(ii)* use semantics (truth table) to show that the formula is a tautology (i.e. $⊨ p ∨ ¬p$) and apply the *Completeness theorem for the calculus*, stating that every tautology is derivable in the calculus to conclude. In this case we are using a result (the completeness of the calculus) proved at the meta-level.

---

The distinction object-meta can be easily understood with the following example : a Chinese grammar written in English.

The Chinese Language is the object of study : the *object-language*, while the English Language is the language used to describe the first one : the *meta-language*.

Comment: I have just read about completeness and soundness. Now I understand that basically, the soundness property of a logic system gives us a way of proof from $\vdash$ to $\models$, i.e. inference rules derivation to truth value table checking when the derivation is not easy to conduct. Combining your answer I know that object-level is the $\vdash$ way and meta-level is the $\models$ way, is that right?

Comment: As I see from the example given at last, the object is more about the inside(kind of close to semantics) while the meta is more about the superficial perspective. Regarding proof, maybe the Truth value checking is kind of superficial and the derivation rules are more to the inner relations. I was just trying to understand the meta and object in proof, so I made the so informal explanation above.

Comment: @BobHU - *semantics* is about the calculus and the object Language, and thus is at the meta-level. Both *soundness* and *completeness* are theorems expressing the link between the Language and calculus and its semantics: thus they are exprfessed and proved at the meta-.